# Insertion sort sorting an ArrayList problems

Tags: java, arraylist, while-loop, insertion-sort

now I have been at this for a while and there is an error I am having.  Now the program I am making is an address book, and I am using an insertion sort to sort an arraylist of objects which I call books(address entries).  Now I soon discovered that my sorter is not sorting properly so I made a simple program to test the sorter and again it does not work.  I was wondering if you guys could have a look at it and help me out.

Here is my Sorter:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
public class Sorts {

    /**
     * Sorts and array of integer from low to high
     * pre: none
     * post: Integers has been sorted from low to high
     */
    public static void insertionSort(ArrayList<String> test) {
        Comparable temp;
        int previousIndex;
        ArrayList<String> objectSort = test;

        for (int i = 1; i < objectSort.size(); i++) {
            temp = objectSort.get(i);
            previousIndex = i - 1;

            while ((objectSort.get(previousIndex).compareTo((String) temp)) == 1 && (previousIndex > 0)) {
                objectSort.set(previousIndex + 1, objectSort.get(previousIndex));
                previousIndex -= 1; //decrease index to compare current item with next previous item
            }
            if (objectSort.get(previousIndex).compareTo((String) temp) == 1) {
                /* shift item in first element up into next element */
                objectSort.set(previousIndex + 1, objectSort.get(previousIndex));
                /* place current item at index 0 (first element */
                objectSort.set(previousIndex, (String) temp);
            } else {
                /* place current item at index ahead of previous item */
                objectSort.set(previousIndex + 1, (String) temp);
            }

        }
    }
}
```

My simple program to test it is:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        ArrayList<String> test = new ArrayList<String>();

        test.add("Roxy");
        test.add("Proxy");
        test.add("Moxy");
        test.add("Samuel Adams");

        Sorts.insertionSort(test);

        System.out.println(test);

    }

}
```

To sum it up, I am having troubles with my ArrayList sorter.  The problem is it wont sort correctly and I do not know why.  Thank you so much in advance.  If you have any questions feel free to ask.  :)

Comment: Can you please show expected output and actual output?

Comment: Any reason why you don't use `Collections.sort(test);`?

Comment: This is for a school assignment.  I choose to make an address book.  One of the prerequisites is to use a sorter or a finder, however they need to be custom made, I cant use classes that are included in java.  I used to use the Insertion sorter for an array and it worked perfectly.  However I decided to use an arraylist to make things more universal and efficient in my program.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First problem: you're expecting `compareTo` to always return 1 for "greater than". It just returns a value *greater than 0* which may be a different positive integer. So both your `== 1` comparisons should be `> 0`.

There may be *other* problems, but that's the first one I'd look at.

Comment: Hey, thank you so much Jon.  It works perfectly.  I will click accept on your answer once 5 minutes is up.  But again, thank you so much. :)

Comment: This was a life saver for my project also! Thank you!